# What does the 'Balance balance' part of getBalance(Balance balance) function mean?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, function

I have this function that is supposed to update a balance in my SQLite database. The parameters are Balance balance. I have a Balance class that i guess is used to help, but I'm unfamiliar with this. I'm used to it saying something like updateBalance(int id, String amount) Can someone just explain to me what is happening here? New to the SQLite world.

My updateBalance function:

```
//Updating single Balance
public int updateBalance(Balance balance){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, balance.getAmount());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_BALANCE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(balance.getID()) });
}
```

My balance class:

```
package com.example.budge_it2;

public class Balance {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _amount;

    //Empty constructor
    public Balance(){

    }
    //Constructor
    public Balance(int id, String amount){
        this._id = id;
        this._amount = amount;
    }

    public Balance(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    //getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    //Setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    //getting amount
    public String getAmount(){
        return this._amount;
    }
    //setting amount
    public void setAmount(String amount){
        this._amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest a good beginner's book on Java. You apparently don't understand what an object is.

Comment: This is why I try to avoid using variable names that are the same as the class it belongs to. Reads funny sometimes.

Comment: Why are you holding numerics in Strings - should be an int or BigDecimal

Comment: I was doing it so that I can use the number right into a textview. Although now I see I can just change it to a String, which I'll probably do later, I figured this would be a quicker way to output it onto my activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Balance` is a domain object here. Instead of passing related primitives around (`ID` and `amount` here); they've been encapsulated into a `Balance` object. That's how data flows through different tiers of an application for example, from a back-end database.

One of the benefits that you get out of it is that your class interface (method signatures) do not change if later down the line you decide to add or remove the data being interchanged. For example, if you feel the need to pass another `Balance` value (say, `overdraft_limit`) later on, you only need to modify the `Balance` class. All other classes exchanging `Balance` objects are insulated from this change.

***EDIT** :*
Your method is returning a `Balance` object

```
public Balance getBalance(int id) { /* code */ }
```

So, at the line when you try to print the return value

```
// You're actually printing Balance obj here
Log.d("Getting : ", "testing " + db.getBalance(1));
```

But, `Balance` is not a primitive so `Log.d()` doesn't know how to print it's `amount` and/or `ID`. So, any time we define a custom class of our own, we usually implement a `toString()` method so as to be able to get its object's textual representation.

So, add the following to your `Balance` class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Balance [ID=" + _id + ", Amount=" + _amount + "]";
}
```

Now, whenever you try to print a `Balance` object, you would see its `_id` and `_amount` displayed.

Comment: Thank you, that helped clear it up. I'm just new to using functions in that way. But as far as SQLite and cursors go, would you be able to explain to me what this getBalance function does?         public Balance getBalance(int id){
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  
 Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BALANCE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_AMOUNT}, KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
  if (cursor != null)
   cursor.moveToFirst();
  
  Balance balance = new Balance(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1));
  return balance;
 }

Comment: @JonFavale, Can you update this method code in your question? Syntax highlighting would help understand.

Comment: ok yeah give me just a minute sorry

Comment: @JonFavale, You need to implement/override `toString()` for your `Balance` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in "int id" or "String amount", the first word is the type and the second word is the parameter name for the instance of that type.